# Cocos2d-x | Errors when Running on Emulator

Tags: c++, eclipse, android-emulator, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I am new to cocos2d-x. I configure cocos2d-x in Windows 8 / Eclipse and I use android-ndk-r8b.
I created a project (HelloWorld)that is running.The program when run in the emulator gives the following errors:

```
05-21 20:17:14.357: E/AndroidRuntime(336): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-21 20:17:14.357: E/AndroidRuntime(336): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start  activity ComponentInfo{com.nabeelahmad.molitx/com.nabeelahmad.molitx.moleitx}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: setRenderer has already been called for this instance.
05-21 20:17:14.357: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
05-21 20:17:14.357: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
05-21 20:17:14.357: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-21 20:17:14.357: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
05-21 20:17:14.357: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-21 20:17:14.357: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-21 20:17:14.357: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-21 20:17:14.357: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-21 20:17:14.357: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-21 20:17:14.357: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-21 20:17:14.357: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-21 20:17:14.357: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-21 20:17:14.357: E/AndroidRuntime(336): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: setRenderer has already been called for this instance.
05-21 20:17:14.357: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.checkRenderThreadState(GLSurfaceView.java:1614)
05-21 20:17:14.357: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(GLSurfaceView.java:355)
05-21 20:17:14.357: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(GLSurfaceView.java:392)
05-21 20:17:14.357: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at com.nabeelahmad.molitx.moleitx.onCreate(moleitx.java:78)
05-21 20:17:14.357: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-21 20:17:14.357: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
05-21 20:17:14.357: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  ... 11 more
```

Anyone have any ideas about what I'm missing or doing wrong?

*Appreciate any help, thanks.*

Answer (score 0):

At first, use latest NDK (android-ndk-r8e at this moment), older NDKs have problems when running cocos2d-x. At second, check that your emulator has option "Use host GPU" turned on.